# How to combine all JPG files in a SubFolder to a "SubFolderName.PDF" file?

Tags: windows, batch, pdf, combine

I have a root directory `C:\ROOT` and this directory contains a number of subfolders, which have the names already ordered in the proper sequence, like:

```
C:\Root\Folder0001
C:\R00t\Folder0002
C:\R00t\Folder0003
...
C:\ROOT\Folder000n
```

The total number of the subfolders is not fixed, but it is available, if necessary. Anyway, all the directories in `C:\Root_Folder` must be processed.

Every subfolder contains JPG files and nothing else and the number of the files in each subfolder is not the same in every subfolder.
The JPG files are already named in the correct sequential order, for example:

```
C:\Root\Folder0001\File0001.jpg
C:\Root\Folder0001\File0002.jpg
C:\Root\Folder0001\File0003.jpg

C:\Root\Folder0002\File0001.jpg
C:\Root\Folder0002\File0002.jpg
C:\Root\Folder0002\File0003.jpg
C:\Root\Folder0002\File0004.jpg
C:\Root\Folder0002\File0005.jpg

C:\Root\Folder0003\File0001.jpg
C:\Root\Folder0003\File0002.jpg

C:\Root\Folder0004\File0001.jpg
C:\Root\Folder0004\File0002.jpg
C:\Root\Folder0004\File0003.jpg
C:\Root\Folder0004\File0004.jpg

C:\Root\Folder0005\File0001.jpg
C:\Root\Folder0005\File0002.jpg
C:\Root\Folder0005\File0003.jpg
C:\Root\Folder0005\File0004.jpg
```

I need a batch file which, given in input the root directory (`C:\ROOT`) merges all the JPG files of a single subfolder in a PDF file and places that PDF file in the subfolder itself.

This must be done for all the subfolders under ROOT, creating a single PDF file for each subfolder.

It would be perfect if, after merging, the JPG files be deleted and if the PDF file had the same name of the containing folder i.e.:

```
C:\Root\Folder0001\Folder0001.pdf
C:\Root\Folder0002\Folder0002.pdf
C:\Root\Folder0003\Folder0003.pdf
C:\Root\Folder0004\Folder0004.pdf
C:\Root\Folder0005\Folder0005.pdf
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Superuser . Given the fact that this can probably not be done natively with a batch file, and you'll need some kind of tool/utility, your question really belongs on the [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Hi. I don't understand why it can't be done natively, since similar questions like "Batch file to combine pdf files in alphabetical order" were answered using a native Windows script and pdftk.exe command, if I am not wrong...
I am trying to deduce the answer that I need from replies in the past.
I will also look at the section that you point out.
Thanks anyway. I strongly hope that someone else chimes in, otherwise I'm in a fix,.

Comment: pdftk is pdftk and not a native batch file command. In the ["Batch file to combine pdf files in alphabetical order"](https://superuser.com/questions/829888/batch-file-to-combine-pdf-files-in-alphabetical-order) question, the OP already knew about pdftk and he was using it in his original script, he just needed guidance on how to make a batch file use it for all files. While you can without anything, looking for the solution (which cannot be done natively in a batch file)

Comment: Yisroel, I too know that pdftk is not a native batch file command and just needed some guidance like the other user.
Never mind. Stay well.

Comment: The question has aspects reaching from  *"Software Recommendations Stack Exchange"* over *"SuperUser"* to *"StackOverflow"*. So I think being here in the middle of all is the right place to ask ;-)

Comment: dodrg and @Io-oI thank you!!! I admit that I am not aware of the different goals of the websites that you mention. I Googled for "batch combine files PDF" and found SuperUser, an excellent place that I already knew of, though...
Now I will carefully study all the info that you provided and put it into practice.
Really, thanks again to you both; greetings from Italy.

Comment: Welcome and thank you for greetings

Comment: Not sure where the close votes are coming from again, this is perfectly suitable for this site in terms of the topic. However, keep in mind for the future that it's not really a free scripting service and questions usually get more answers if you show what you attempt yourself first. You can learn modern PowerShell much more easily than batch for such tasks.

Comment: Destroy666, you are right and I know about what you said, but I am starting right now to create scripts...
PowerShell? Good to know! Thanks & greetings!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The traditional batch using the tools provided by Windows cannot generate a PDF. You'll need to install a separate tool.

To convert images to PDF  [Ghostscript](https://www.ghostscript.com/) would be enough. A sample how to use it can be found at [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52703123/override-default-imagemagick-policy-xml) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52703123/override-default-imagemagick-policy-xml).

As the samples shows, working with Ghostscript is no fun. I recommend to add the tool package [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/) ([Download for Windows](https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows)). For PDF creation it relies on Ghostscript and offers a quite straight forward commandline:

```
convert "*.jpg" -quality 80 -adjoin "result.pdf"
```

This will convert all JPEG files (`*.jpg`) of the current directory in alphabetic sorting order to the file `result.pdf`. While doing this it will compress the JPEGs with the compression quality of 80% (`-quality 80`) and add each JPEG as a new page to the document (`-adjoin`).

To wrap this in a batch that

- recurses all sub-directories of the current position
- creates a PDF of all JPEGs in the current sub-directory
- names the PDF by the same name as the current sub-directory
- deletes the JPEGs when done (here disabled by `REM`)

File: `create-all-pdfs.bat`

```
@echo off
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%i in (`dir /b /s /a:d`) do @(
    echo %%i
    Magick convert "%%i\*.jpg" -quality 80 -adjoin "%%i\%%~nxi.pdf" 2>nul
    REM   if NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 del "%%i\*.jpg"
)
```

*The deletion of the files after PDF creation is commented out for safeguard.

=> Uncomment **at your own risk!**

=> But first read the annotations.*

Better, after you created and verified the PDFs, you execute this
batch from within the same folder to delete recursively all the JPEGs:

File:  `delete-all-jpegs.bat`

```
@echo off
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%i in (`dir /b /s /a:d`) do @(
    echo %%i
    del "%%i\*.jpg"
)
```

##### Annotation 1: The right image size

PDF handles document pages. Such document pages have real measurements (centimeters/inches). So a picture that will be inserted in a PDF page is expected to have its density defined in the meta data (i.e. 300ppi).
If this is not the case or the value is not fitting, the image probably will be displayed to small or to large.

- Either you define the correct value in the JPEG
- Or you can define by the `Magick` command parameters a value to be used for the processed images:
  `-density 300` defines a picture that shall have 300 ppi (pixel per inch)

```
Magick convert "%%i\*.jpg" -density 300 -quality 80 -adjoin "%%i\%%~nxi.pdf"
```

If the pictures display to small in the PDF, reduce the density value.

##### Annotation 2:  JPEG will be recoded

You need to know that Imagemagick's `convert` will always interpret the image. So the JPEG will be re-encoded while its processing into the PDF. As JPEG uses destructive compression this is relevant.
To achieve the best results, your JPEGs should *not* be stored with compression (Quality: 100%). The compression should be done by Imagemagick's `convert`.

##### Annotation 3:  Variables in Batch / commandline

Please note that these code lines are written for execution within a batch file. There a command variable must have a doubled `%` => `%%i`.

At the commandline you have to use only one `%` => `%i`.

##### Annotation 4:  How to display the current JPEG file

> How do I echo the file (not only the folder %%i) which is currently being processed?

First thing to realize is, that the batch itself currently does not know any filenames, it only knows the directory names that it passes over to `Magick convert`.

To display the currently handled filename there are two variants:

**1. Output by the cmd shell routines**

To do this by the cmd shell the batch has to be rewritten to evaluate every JPEG filename and pass it over to `Magick` one by one.

The problem with this is the performance, as you want to fill all JPEGs of one directory in one PDF. So *the PDF gets rewritten for every single JPEG!* instead of creating it only once.

Replacing the `Magick ...` line in the script by this code scrap would do it but is *DEPRECIATED*:

```
for %%f in  ("%%i\*.jpg") do @(
    Magick convert   "%%i\%%~nxi.pdf" "%%f" -quality 80 -adjoin "%%i\%%~nxi.pdf"
)
```

Better:

**2. Ask `Magick` to display the current filename**

The problem with this is that Magick is not a tool for making nice output but for making a smart image handling. — At least I didn't find a *simple* option to just display the currently processed image file.

The option `-verbose` contains this info but goes far beyond this.
So I filtered the output of `-verbose` to do the trick. Here the final extended script:

```
@echo off
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%i in (`dir /b /s /a:d`) do @(
    echo %%i
    Magick convert "%%i\*.jpg" -quality 80 -adjoin -verbose "%%i\%%~nxi.pdf" 2>nul | (
        for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=>=[" %%f in (
            'find /v "1x1"'
        ) do @(
            echo %%g | find /v /i ".pdf" >nul && echo %%f
            echo %%g | find /i ".pdf"
        )
    )

    REM   if NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 del "%%i\*.jpg"
)
```

*Note, that the option `-verbose` **must** be written between the source file and the destination file!*

There would have been a slightly easier variant to filter the `-verbose`, but by the current variant the file is really *displayed at the time of processing*. And at the end the assembling of the PDF file also costs relevant time so it is displayed too.
If you prefer not to see the final PDF eliminate the line `echo %%g | find /i ".pdf"`.

Comment: About Annotaion 2: I know meanwhile `Ghostscript` has added a feature *"JPEG passthrough"* to circumvent the re-encoding of a JPEG while creating the PDF. But the documentation for this is "well hidden" and if `ImageMagick` supports it is another question. // Perhaps someone has some details?

Comment: I have now studied your answer and put it into practice.
It works perfectly and I understood concepts that were not clear to me.
It is my desire to thank you deeply for the effort and the detail level that you put in it.

Comment: If my solution served you, you should set the solved hook. If you think the answer is of value you can additionally add an upvote.

Comment: I gave you the upvote and I would have done the same to Io-oI, since his solution is good, too, but I found out that I can upvote only one user. I find this sort of uncomfortable...
Hem.... How do I "set the solved hook"?

Comment: The "solved" hook is for the solution *you are going to use*. So not necessarily the acknowledged answer is the best solution, its just the solution you've chosen. // To acknowledge the efforts, as they are good, well written, etc. you can give each answer (or question) an upvote, so honoring their efforts, too.

Comment: Now I understood, thanks. Upvote to you both is the minimum.

Comment: This is your script, that I used several times in the last days (thanks again!).


`@echo off
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%i in (``dir /b /s /a:d``) do 
@(
echo %%i
Magick convert "%%i\*.jpg" -quality 80 -adjoin 
"%%i\%%~nxi.pdf"
REM   if NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 del "%%i\*.jpg"
)`



How do I echo the file (not only the folder %%i) which is currently being processed?
I tried with:


`echo %%i\*.*`


but it doesn't work....
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Updated answer to also display the filenames.

Comment: @KJ The essential point for this question is, that for the usage **within a batch** Windows does not provide acceptable PDF creation support. Windows (the GUI-system) is a different theme.

Comment: @dodrg I saw: thanks again ! So the difference is 2 > nul ? OK, I learned something more!

Comment: @EnricoPriotti · No, the `2>nul` is just a correction to prohibit error messages. They would appear when a folder does not contain any `*.jpg` . The important part is the extra code in the line: `Magick ... -verbose ... 2>nul | (` and at the following lines until the empty line.   // `-verbose` will produce some output and the extra routines  will filter the overhead of the output, so only the filename (with path) remains. (See the full script at the updated end of my answer)

Comment: @dodrg  Oh, I just saw. There is a whole new section in your code....
By the way:
- your script works also with PNG images (placing `*.*``) and I had to put 70% quality level if I wanted to get a compression level high enough to compensate for the size increase created by the PDF combine.--
Thank you very much!

Comment: `*.*` is not a good advice. In this case you must be sure there is no other file in the recursed directories. Better you write `Magick "%%i\*.png" "%%i\*.jpg" ...`

Comment: @dodrg Ah, good to know (of course I check all the filetypes before running your script....)! I wrote down everything and I'm studying it. By the way I noticed that you not only added a section to your script, but to the description, too! Really precious, thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

```bat
@echo off 

cd /d "D:\Full\Path\To\Ur\Given\In\Input\The\Root\Dir"

set "_jpeg2pdf="D:\The\Full\Path\To\Bin\jpeg2pdf.exe""
set "_jpeg2pdf=%_jpeg2pdf% -p A4 -n auto -z fit -c none .\*.jpg -o"

for /r /d %%i in (*)do chDir /d "%%~dpnxi" && =;(
     @%_jpeg2pdf% ".\%%~nxi.pdf" | find /i ".pdf"
     if exist ".\\%%~nxi.pdf" 2>nul del ".\*.jpg"
    );=

"%__AppDir__%tree.com" /f /a "%~dp0" | "%__AppDir__%more.com"
```

---

## ***[`jpeg2pdf.exe`](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jpeg2pdf/files/1.1/jpeg2pdf_1.1_win32.zip/download)***

***[Create PDF from JPEG scans and photos by: @dmitry-markin, @haohu](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jpeg2pdf/files/1.1/jpeg2pdf_1.1_win32.zip/download)***

**HOW TO USE**

**1.** Create PDF `document.pdf` from all JPEG files **in current directory**:

```cmd
    jpeg2pdf *.jpg -o document.pdf
```

**2.** Create PDF `scans.pdf` with:
page size determined by maximum image size,
page orientation forced to `portrait`,
preserve the original dpi of images (don't scale),
crop the height of each page at image borders
(yields good results for scans with white background and correct dpi)

```cmd
    jpeg2pdf -o scans.pdf -p auto -n portrait -z none -r height *.jpg
```

**3.** Create PDF 'from_photos.pdf' with:
A5 paper size,
landscape orientation,
fit the width of images (`fw` -- fit width),
crop the height of each page
(works well for properly cropped photos of A5 pages in landscape
with unknown/wrong dpi and approximately correct widths)

```cmd
    jpeg2pdf -o from_photos.pdf -p A5 -n landscape -z fw -r height *.jpg
```

**4.** It is possible to specify the title, author, subject, keyword, and creator
of produced PDF document with switches `-t, -a, -s, -k, -c`:

```cmd
    jpeg2pdf -o doc.pdf -t "The Title of PDF" -a Andrew -c jpeg2pdf *.jpg
```

---

**PROJECT HOME**

**http://sourceforge.net/projects/jpeg2pdf/**

---

```
> jpeg2pdf.exe -h
Usage: jpeg2pdf.exe [options] filemask-1 ... [filemask-N]
  -o output        output PDF file name. required.
  [-p papersize]   A0-A10,Letter,Legal,Junior,Ledger,Tabloid,auto default:A4
  [-n orientation] auto,portrait,landscape default:auto
  [-m marginsize]  margins size in inches (specify 'mm' for millimeters) default:0
  [-z scale]       fit,fw,fh,reduce,rw,rh,none default:fit
  [-r crop]        none,height,width,both default:none crop/expand page to image size
  [-t title]       default: none
  [-a author]      default: current user name
  [-k keywords]    default: input files list
  [-s subject]     default: 'Generated from JPEG images'
  [-c creator]     default: 'jpeg2pdf'
  [-h]             display this help
  filemask-...     input JPEG file name. requires at least one. wildcards '*' and '?' allowed.
```

---

I tend to make priority use of simplified binaries, and based on that I always made use of jpeg2pdf to convert jpg to pdf, so I'm kind of suspicious to speak well of it, so I'll just say that I prefer it because it's simple and it's served me well whenever I used it.

---

Just note that the softer doesn't get along very well with file paths, it prefers to handle them locally (***HOW TO USE*** item ***1.***), so it's necessary to go to the folder where the files are for the conversion to be done.

```bat
jpeg2pdf.exe "D:\Full\Path\To\Ur\Given\In\Input\The\Root\Dir\*.jpg" "%%~nxi.pdf"

chDir /d "%%~dpnxi"
jpeg2pdf.exe *.jpg ".\%%~nxi.pdf"
```

---

So, download the `jpeg2pdf` and put it in some folder and replace the relevant path..

```bat
set "_jpeg2pdf="D:\The\Full\Path\To\Bin\jpeg2pdf.exe""
```

---

You can use a **`for /d /r`** loop, which will go through all the folders recursively, and in each folder inside the loop, use the **`cd /d`** command followed by the **`jpeg2pdf`** to convert your **`jpg`** in the current folder and once it's done, delete all *.jpg in the folder if the pdf was generate there.

- ```
  FOR /R - Loop through files (recursively)
  FOR /D - Loop through several folders/directories
  ```
- ```
  The option /D /R is undocumented, but can be a useful combination,
  while it will recurse through all subfolders the wildcard will only
  match against Folder/Directory names (not filenames)
  Note: Source linked to ss64.com
  ```

---

---

**Additional resources:**

- [`Set /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html)
- [`For /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)
- [`For /R /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html)
- [`For /D /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html)
- [`Tree /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/tree.html)
- [`More /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/more.html)
- [Conditional Execution](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)

  - [`||`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html) and [`&&`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)
- [Commands Redirection](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php)

  - `|`, `<`, `>`, `2>`, etc.
- [`If() Else If() Else()` Condictions](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html)
- [Windows Environment Variables (Refer: `%__DirApp__%`)](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html)
- [How does the Windows Command Interpreter [`cmd.exe`] Parse Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4094699/6819406)

Comment: thank you very much for all this information that you gave me., which I studied in depth I tried the batch and it works as required. Now I have two scripts available to solve my problem!
Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

The OP implied challenge was to just use Windows native Opp. System to produce PDF from merged JPG's in a folder. Actually it is very simple to merge using Windows TAR into a zip but harder to convert that to PDF without a GUI app.

There are may comments about "not possible" which I will agree its so difficult but **not impossible given certain Windows abilities**.

So invalid to intent will be using PowerShell PSWritePDF module which can merge pdfs etc. but imports Apryse iText (as a download), see later comment.

What is possible is to use JScript to write a text wrapper around baseline JPEG's as they embed naturally in a PDF as a page. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/75710613/10802527 for the principles.

At this point I will say I can **write a Console.CMD script to do that task fairly easily (JPEG/MP4)** but life is short so there is a proof of concept for single files at https://github.com/GitHubRulesOK/MyNotes/blob/master/jpgTOpdf.zip

This snippet is a text file to generate a small PDF as POC for JScript (or WSH or VBS) which is easier to run fast as a double click.js
[image]
NOTE Notepad does not corrupt this ANSI binary but Web copy and paste will, so here is a link for download https://github.com/GitHubRulesOK/MyNotes/blob/master/JScriptSamples/HWR%26Wstream.js

```js
var ByteStream = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Stream");
ByteStream.Type = 2; // Writer
ByteStream.Charset = "Windows-1252"; //Best for PDF writer
var BS = ByteStream; // Abreviate for ease of edit
BS.Open();
BS.Position = 0;

BS.WriteText("%PDF-1.0\n");
BS.WriteText("%ÅÑ§¡\n");

BS.WriteText("1 0 obj <</Type/Catalog/Pages 2 0 R>> endobj\n");
BS.WriteText("2 0 obj <</Type/Pages/Count 1/Kids[3 0 R]>> endobj\n");
BS.WriteText("3 0 obj <</Type/Page/MediaBox[0 0 144 144]/Rotate 0/Resources<</XObject<</Img0 4 0 R>>>>/Contents 5 0 R/Parent 2 0 R>> endobj\n");
BS.WriteText("4 0 obj <</Type/XObject/Subtype/Image/Height 25/Width 24/BitsPerComponent 1/Length 75/ColorSpace[/Indexed/DeviceRGB 1<FF0000FFFFFF>]>> stream\n");
BS.WriteText('ÿÿÿÿÿÿÀmß[}ÑoEÑ[EÑqEßE}ÀUÿñÿÁ«Á¬ÛZcýÖÇÈ"}ÿÕïÀMsß`§Ñ]9ÑNÑE·ßLÇÀA[ÿÿÿÿÿÿ');
BS.WriteText("\nendstream\nendobj\n");
var Pos1 = "000000000"+BS.Position
BS.WriteText("5 0 obj <</Length 101>> stream\n");
BS.WriteText("q\n1 0 0 -1 18 54 cm\n35 0 0 -36 0 36 cm\n/Img0 Do\nQ\nq\n1 0 0 -1 71 144 cm\n70 0 0 -72 0 72 cm\n/Img0 Do\nQ\n");
BS.WriteText("\nendstream\nendobj\n\n");
var Pos2 = BS.Position
BS.WriteText("xref\n0 6\n");
BS.WriteText("0000000000 00001 f \n0000000015 00000 n \n0000000060 00000 n \n0000000111 00000 n \n0000000237 00000 n \n"+Pos1.slice(-10)+" 00000 n \n");
BS.WriteText("\ntrailer\n<</Size 6/Info<</Producer(JScrip2pdf)>>/Root 1 0 R>>\nstartxref\n"+Pos2+"\n%%EOF\n");

BS.SaveToFile("HelloWorldR&W.pdf", 2);
BS.Close();
```

Thus it would be possible to add a folder of JPEG if one spent enough time scripting.

So I am not providing an answer as such to OP since PowerShell has access to more powerful libraries.

Thus I would write a "for loop" to mass convert each JPEG to wrapped PDF then in the folder use a Powershell merge as described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/75524955

Comment: K J, thank you so much! This is the first time I learn something about JavaScript. I am now studying the Windows scripting.... Greetings!

Comment: I understand. Thank you so much for the explanation! For the moment I think that it's better for me to stick to Windows Scripting. Greetings!